# Constraint/AutoLayout Orientation Issue

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, avfoundation, orientation-changes

I had a question about how exactly I can accomplish dealing with a change in orientation. So essentially, here's what I'm trying to do. As part of the app, I'm working on I have a barcode scanning feature that uses the native AVFoundation in order to scan barcodes. Now, as part of this controller, I have a view that I render in the form of a rectangle on screen which essentially is the part where the actual scanning happens (using the rectOfInterest property). In terms of code, this is how I have things set up:

```
UIView *scanBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:scanBoxFrame];
[[scanBox layer]setBorderColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[[scanBox layer]setBorderWidth:2.0];


[[self view] addSubview:scanBox];
[[self view] bringSubviewToFront:scanBox];
```

Now this works as expected in portrait mode, however once I rotate the screen because I'm not really doing any autolayout or constraints, nothing really happes and so my view which was previously rendered as a rectangle now obviously looks like a square, now essentially what I need to happen is for my view to rotate accordingly so that even in landscape mode, my view appears as a rectangle and hence serves as a visual cue for users so they know how to focus and scan the barcodes. I would really appreciate any tips/ideas/code samples that you could provide that could help me. I should add that I'm doing all of this programatically, so using storyboards for this particular piece is not an option.

Thanks!

Comment: Bump! Anybody have any ideas?